# Difference between Tests and Steps in testng

Tags: testng, extentreports, extent, test-reporting, test-results

I am new to testng, i am using testng with extent report. In extent report i see two charts as Tests and Steps. My total test has 2 pass and 4 failures which i see in test chart, i dont know what is steps chart.

Can some one explain me the **difference between Tests and Steps**. I attached my extentreport.

My testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.ttn.Test.Functionality2"/>
      <class name="com.ttn.Test.Functionality1"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

[image]
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Tests defines: Total test section which you have created in your Report: Which has the syntax like : `extentReport.createTest("name of section")`

Steps defines : Total number of log which you have generated in Script, Which has syntax like : `testlog.info()` OR `testlog.pass()` OR `testlog.fail()`  where testlog is object of ExtentTest class,

Refer below example for more clarification : 
[image: Image of Report]

In this report, there are 3 section which has been created and its showing as Tests. And Steps defines numbers of logs which has been passed in Script.